# How to make telegram bot reply with a photo?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have this telegram bot, and i want it to reply to a specific message with a specific photo, to be something like this

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

def text(update, context):
    text_received = update.message.text
    if text_received == "12345":
        update.message.reply_photo(open('df.png', 'r'))
    else:
        update.message.reply_text(f'Did you say "{text_received}"?')
def main():
    TOKEN = "TOKEN"

    updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))

    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, text))

    dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I got this error

```
Photo_invalid_dimensions
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: What does "didn't work" means in your case , can you be more specific ?

Comment: bot replies with "an error occurs" which my function does in case of errors

Comment: Sounds like you should set up proper logging and/or error handling. See [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Exception-Handling) for more info.

Comment: @CallMeStag question updated with the error

Comment: @CallMeStag my answer was literally not correct, since he's currently using an updater and not the proper object "chatbot" instantiated with class "Bot".

Comment: It was still correct that the photo should be opened in bytes mode, i.e. `update.message.reply_photo(open('df.png', 'rb'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `sendPhoto` docs [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#sendphoto):

- The photo must be at most 10 MB in size.
- The photo's width and height must not exceed 10000 in total.
- Width and height ratio must be at most 20.

Based on the error you receive, your photo's width/height doesn't comply to the second rule. You can use `sendDocument` method which is `reply_document` instead of `reply_photo`.

Comment: reply_document did the trick for me, thanks a lot!!